# Airdrop Text File From Mac To iPhone Issue

Tags: iphone, notes.app, airdrop

When I airdrop a text file from my Mac to my iPhone, the phone automatically opens the contents as a new Apple Note. Not sure why it started doing this. I used to get the pop up menu that allowed to choose how to open the transfer.

How do I get the AirDrop Open with... pop up to launch for text files?